# Change value of a Text widget (NOT TextField)

Tags: flutter

I am trying to set up a text widget in my flutter app, and have the value change based on other widgets.

I can only find tips on how to change a TextField, but I don't want this to be editable by the user, only by code.

I can't set the data value of the widget, because it's final.

Is there any way to make this work in Flutter?

Comment: Continue with the flutter tutorials and you will figure it out. It can be done with a stateful widget

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/enabled.html
I believe you modify these two fields and add stateful widget with setState